# Was there a zamanu jahilliya(Era of ignorance) after the Prophet (PBUH)?

Tags: practical-islam, history

I am not that good at Tarikh, Islamic history, but I am concerned with how Islam is so divided more so in this generation. There is a lot of versions of simple things such as how the Prophet (PBUH) used to dress? Or even something every person performs every day or must perform. Where do we put our arms when we stand in our prayers? My question is was there an era where a lot of Islamic content was distorted or people were not that careful in transmitting the knowledge?

Comment: What is your question about in specific: 1) a second or subsequent era of ignorance, or 2) distortion of Islamic content (you narrow it down to only being careless about transmitting knowledge as the only cause), or 3) divisions among Muslims, or 4) inquiring about specific habits of the Prophet ﷺ outside Islam (e.g., the way he dressed), or 5) inquiring about Sunnah (where to put arms when standing in prayers)? Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help].